How to perform a select by sections since it contains many records using Java?
I have a table which contains approximately 100,000 records, I did a SELECT to obtain the total number of records because it can vary, I need to consult the table and obtain all the records of 4 specific fields(nombre, apellido, puesto) but since it contains a lot of information it takes too long,
I am thinking of doing it in parts, that is making a SELECT that brings me only 10 000 records and with a FOR iterates until reaching the maximum number of records that the table has and at the same time these records are stored in a list since after obtaining these records I need to insert them into another table.
this is my code but it doesn't do anything.
I'm not sure if the for is done correctly, what I want to do is for the select to be performed until the maximum number of records is reached, and for the data to be saved in the Employees type list
Could someone correct me or tell me how the FOR should look like to obtain the 100,000 records and have them stored in the list?
public class TestConnect {

    List<Empleados> empleadoList;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
          
        TestConnect test = new TestConnect();
        test.read();


    }

    //metodo para traer los datos de la tabla empleados
    public void read() {
        String user = "postgres";
        String pss = "admin123";

        empleadoList = new ArrayList<>();
        Empleados empleado = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        PreparedStatement stm = null;
        Connection connect = null;
        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd_test", user, pss);
            PreparedStatement stmCount = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) from empleados");
            ResultSet resultCount = stmCount.executeQuery();

            int records = 0;
            while (resultCount.next()) {
                records = resultCount.getInt(1);
            }
            System.out.println(" RECORDS    " + records);

            for (int i = 0; i <= records; i += 10000) {
                stm = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM empleados limit 10000");
                result = stm.executeQuery();
                while (result.next()) {

                    empleado = new Empleados();
                    empleado.setId(result.getInt("id"));
                    empleado.setNombre(result.getString("nombre"));
                    empleado.setApellido(result.getString("apellido"));
                    empleado.setPuesto(result.getString("puesto"));
                    empleadoList.add(empleado);
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        } finally {
            try {
                result.close();
                stm.close();
                connect.close();

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        }
    }


}


Maybe it would be better to do your mass processing in the database instead of allocating records in empleadoList? It would be orders of magnitude faster and safer.

I did a SELECT to obtain the total number of records because it can vary So? Currently that query serves no purpose at all. Don't SELECT *. Don't have empty exception blocks. Don't have plural class names when they should be singular and do use try-with-resources


select only what you need, so specify the columns you want.
Set a fetch-size to retrieve bigger blocks of rows at once (reduces the round trips to the database)
Use a proper connection pool as creating DB connections is a heavy operation.

public void read() {
    String user = "postgres";
    String pss = "admin123";

    empleadoList = new ArrayList<>();        
    try (   var connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd_test", user, pss);
            var stmt = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT id, nombre, apellido, puesto FROM empleados");) {
            stmt.setFetchSize(1000)
            var result = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                Empleados empleado = new Empleados();
                empleado.setId(result.getInt("id"));
                empleado.setNombre(result.getString("nombre"));
                empleado.setApellido(result.getString("apellido"));
                empleado.setPuesto(result.getString("puesto"));
                empleadoList.add(empleado);
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Something like this. To use a proper connection pool you would need to create a DataSource with something like Hikari Connectionpool and reuse that in places you need DB access.

Create a Postgres View
`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_view as SELECT a, b, c, d from test1`

it will return only those 4 columns.
you don't need for statement in that case.
call the view using
`connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * from test_view")`


Just specify the columns you need in the select statement, no need to create a (materialized) view for that.

Materialized view improves performance.

Refer to this blog, how Materialized View Improves Performance https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230665/materialized-views-performance

You also need to keep them in sync etc. so yes they might improve performance but doesn't mean it is the solution to this problem, especially with so little as 100000 rows.
